# Screen session dies randomly and how can I diagnose the reason?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, display, python

I'm using a Python script with `screen` session but it dies randomly and I checked syslog files for an error (which mentioned on [Screen and SSH Tunnel - How can screen session possibly die?](https://superuser.com/questions/295767/screen-and-ssh-tunnel-how-can-screen-session-possibly-die)) but couldn't find any error or something to diagnose the problem.

Is there any way to diagnose the underlying problem?

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4, Python 3 for scripts.

Comment: Can you show how you invoke `screen` and then the script? Something like `screen -dm my_script` will cause the screen session to end together with the program for example.

Comment: Hello @EduardoTrápani, I'm using `screen -S sessionname` and then running Python script under virtualenv. The script doesn't end normally, it waits for incoming data infinitely... I guess there should be an I/O problem but it doesn't happen without screen.

Comment: So, you open the session and then **from the shell** you run python? Screen should not end the session, you should be returned to the shell. This question [Screen session terminates when program crashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168202/screen-session-terminates-when-program-crashes) has some ideas on how to debug it.

Comment: Also, can you be specific on how you "exit" the `screen` session?  Make sure you are not terminating it when you exit.